# Ionic - Angular - Two out of three input of a component have undefined value

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, input

I have a problem with `@input()`, two out of three input have an undefined value when I want to use it but can be display using interpolation in the template file.

.ts :

```
export class NoteCanvasPageComponent {
  @Input() note: any;
  @Input() canvasWidth: any;
  @Input() canvasHeight: any;

  @ViewChild("TextArea") textArea: any;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.note.posY + " " + this.canvasHeight);
    console.log(this.note.posX + " " + this.canvasWidth);
    this.textArea.nativeElement.style.top = this.note.posY * this.canvasHeight;
    this.textArea.nativeElement.style.left = this.note.posX * this.canvasWidth;
  }

}
```

`console.log()` print this :
`0.623 undefined 
 0.578 undefined`

template file :

```
<textarea #TextArea class="note-canvas-page">
  {{note.text}}
  {{canvasHeight}}
  {{canvasWidth}}
</textarea>
```

Give :
`This is a note
512
360`

Why only two out of three input have undefined value in the component file ?

I use the component like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let note of arrayNotes">
  <note-canvas-page [canvasHeight]=canvasHeight [canvasWidth]=canvasWidth [note]=note *ngIf="note.display"></note-canvas-page>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you sure that canvasHeight and canvasWidth is already set when assigning to   note-canvas-page?

Comment: where you are initializing the variable canvasHeight and canvaswidth??

Comment: @mvermand Yes I think, I use this variable in the parent component and the value can be display using `{{canvasHeight}}` in note-canvas-page

Comment: You're missing the "" around `canvasHeight`, `canvasWidth `, `note `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution might be:

```
export class NoteCanvasPageComponent {
  _canvasWidth: any;
  _canvasHeight: any;
  _note: any;

  @Input() 
  set note(value: any) {
      this._note = value;
      initComponent();
  }

  get note() {
      return this._note;
  }

  @Input() 
  set canvasWidth(value: any) {
      this._canvasWidth = value;
      initComponent();
  }

  get canvasWidth() {
      return this._canvasWidth ;
  }

  @Input() 
  set canvasHeight(value : any) {
      this._canvasHeight = value;
      initComponent();
  }

  get canvasHeight() {
      return this._canvasHeight ;
  }

  @ViewChild("TextArea") textArea: any;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){

  }

  initComponent() {
    if(this._note && this._canvasWidth && this._canvasHeight) {
        console.log(this._note.posY + " " + this._canvasHeight);
        console.log(this._note.posX + " " + this._canvasWidth);
        this.textArea.nativeElement.style.top = this._note.posY * this.canvasHeight;
        this.textArea.nativeElement.style.left = this._note.posX * this._canvasWidth;
    }
  }

}
```

This has the added value that style.top and style.left will be recalculated whenever note, canvasHeight or canvasWidth changes.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change your code to the following:

```
export class NoteCanvasPageComponent {
  _canvasWidth: any;

  @Input() note: any;

  @Input() 
  set canvasWidth(value: any) {
      debugger;                     // <-- breakpoint 1
      this._canvasWidth = value;
  }

  @Input() canvasHeight: any;

  @ViewChild("TextArea") textArea: any;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    debugger;          // <-- breakpoint 2
    console.log(this.note.posY + " " + this.canvasHeight);
    console.log(this.note.posX + " " + this._canvasWidth);
    this.textArea.nativeElement.style.top = this.note.posY * this.canvasHeight;
    this.textArea.nativeElement.style.left = this.note.posX * this._canvasWidth;
  }

}
```

This code will break in two places. See if it reaches breakpoint 1 before breakpoint 2 and see what the value is in breakpoint 1.

Comment: Debbuger said that the value is undefined so you're right, the input isn't already set when assigning to note-canvas-page. But I still don't understand why `{{canvasHeight}}` works

Comment: Then look at my second answer, that might fix your issue. It will recalculate whenever something changes to your inputs, even after ngInit or ngAfetrViewInit

Comment: {{canvasHeight}} works because the input is set after the ngAfterViewInit is already executed. Any change at any moment to your input will be reflected in {{canvasHeight}}, but the ngAfterViewInit is only executed once. If the canvasHeight is not yet set at that moment, calculation will not be as desired

Comment: Yes, it works with some change ! Thank you very much for the solution and the explanations :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace this:

```
 <div *ngFor="let note of arrayNotes">
      <note-canvas-page [canvasHeight]=canvasHeight [canvasWidth]=canvasWidth [note]=note *ngIf="note.display"></note-canvas-page>
    </div>
```

with:

```
    <div *ngFor="let note of arrayNotes">
      <note-canvas-page [canvasHeight]=note.canvasHeight [canvasWidth]=note.canvasWidth [note]=note *ngIf="note.display"></note-canvas-page>
    </div>
```

Comment: canvasHeight and Width aren't attribute of note object.